# Can't connect to email without VPN

Tags: vpn, internet

2010 MacPro. I updated from High Sierra to Mojave as I had the right GPU.

Now, when I try to log in to email, first choice, using Thunderbird, it doesn't connect. Then I tried to go to Comcast's web mail. and saw the usual note at the bottom of the browser -

[image]

but then -

[image]

Able to sign in to my account for billing, etc, just not mail.

I then tried other browsers and got similar warnings.

I then turned on my VPN (I happen to use Winscribe) and both Thunderbird and browser based mail come through.

This occured with the update to Mojave, and I'm trying to understand what setting was changed and how I can avoid needing the VPN to run to get mail.

To be clear, I have no issues signing into other secure sites, and no issue signing into Comcast email from non-Mojave Mac or my second Pro also running MoJave.

Trying to methodically isolate source of the issue, and don't really know my next step.

Update - I started up in "safe mode" and no difference. Last, I started in recovery mode, to re-install the OS, but got an error that I need to be using a metal compatible card (I am, Mojave running fine) and that filevault needs to be turned off, which it is.

Comment: Have you tried connecting from another network (such as an iPhone hotspot)? Does the website work on other machines on the same network as your Mac Pro?

Comment: I just tried to sign in from my other MacPro running Mojave. No issue. And that one has no VPN running.